# Spring boot WebService Rest (PERSONALIZAR RESPONSE)

Tags: java, webservice, spring-boot

Deseo personalizar la respuesta cuando es un Status 405 Method Not Allowed

```
{
    "timestamp": 1527270306717,
    "status": 405,
    "error": "Method Not Allowed",
    "exception": "org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException",
    "message": "Request method 'POST' not supported",
    "path": "/students/Student1/courses"
}
```

Esa es la respuesta predeterminada y me gustaria customizarla eh utilizado esto y no funciona

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED)
@ExceptionHandler(HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException.class)
public String handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException(HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException e) {
    System.out.println("cualquier cosa para saber si pasa por aqui");
    return null;
}
```

por otra parte tengo otro Exceptionhandler y en este si entra cuando es otro codigo como 409 o 400 , y el 405 no

```
@ExceptionHandler({RuntimeException.class,HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException.class})
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorDTO> processRuntimeException(HttpServletRequest req, RuntimeException ex) throws Exception {

    return null;
}
```

¿Alguien sabe como resolverlo?

Comment: Hola que tal. ¿Pudiste resolverlo? Aqui te pongo una pregunta que trata el asunto. https://stackoverflow.com/a/27223978/4326551

Comment: Capaz podrias usar dentro de una clase algo asi como @RestControllerAdvice

Answer (score 1):

Claro tu puedes personalizar tu propio mensaje de error con los siguientes  pasos:

1. Tu debes crearte un mensage de error personalizado el cual quieres mostrar.

   ```
   public class MensageDeError {
   ```

   ```
   private HttpStatus status;
   private String mensaje;
   private List<String> errores;

   public MensageDeError(HttpStatus status, String mensaje, List<String> errores) {
       super();
       this.status = status;
       this.mensaje = mensaje;
       this.errores = errores;
   }

   public MensageDeError(HttpStatus status, String mensaje, String error) {
       super();
       this.status = status;
       this.mensaje = mensaje;
       errores = Arrays.asList(error);
   }
   ```

   }
2. Tu debes crearte un manejador de excepciones personalizable para manejar la excepcion que esta saliendo en este caso es HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException.

   @ControllerAdvice
       public class PersonalizableManejedorDeExcepciones extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
           @Override
           protected ResponseEntity handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported(
                   HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException ex,
                   HttpHeaders headers,
                   HttpStatus status,
                   WebRequest request) {
               StringBuilder constructor = new StringBuilder();
               constructor.append(ex.getMethod());
               constructor.append(
                       " metodo no es soportado para este request. Meotodos soportados son: ");
               ex.getSupportedHttpMethods().forEach(t -> constructor.append(t + " "));

   MensajeDeError mensajeDeError = new MensajeDeError(HttpStatus.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED,
                   ex.getLocalizedMessage(), constructor.toString());
           return new ResponseEntity<Object>(
                   mensajeDeError, new HttpHeaders(), mensajeDeError.getStatus());
       }
   }